# Multiple-site configuration for home page

Tags: joomla-3.x

We have a multi-site configuration. Some sites are English and some are other languages. My problem is that my site in English has a featured article set as the Home page. If you go to another site and type this in:

`www.examplesite1.com/index.php`

It will show the content from my main site. The problem is typing in the `index.php` part. I obviously don't want this. It is not a problem for my other sites using a different language because I can assign a different home page. But for all the English sites I have it uses the same Home page. AFAIK you can't assign multiple home pages to the same language.

I tried to use Advanced module manager and move this into a separate module and create an assignment to only the proper domain but that doesn't' work. Anyone know of any alternatives I can try?

I don't do anything special for this multi-site configuration just a [simple template redirect](https://docs.joomla.org/Multiple_Domains_and_Web_Sites_in_a_single_Joomla!_installation).

Comment: Too stupid to put as answer, but your template redirect **does** have the test for "www.examplesite1.com/index.php" and "examplesite1.com/index.php" in addition to the "www.examplesite1.com/" and "examplesite1.com/" shown in the example. The code in the example does not recognize the url with index.php added.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Joomla does not have a multiple-site configuration.

If you want to manage several independent sites on the same hosting account, then you can create hostings on subdirectories or subdomains. All of these alternatives have to be defined at hosting level.

Comment: Several sites are already running in production in a multi-site configuration. That's not the question. The question is specific to how can I remove the article set as home from these other sites.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you want to achieve by pasting into the index.php file, can also be achieved by creating a system plugin and triggering the same code onAfterInitialise

However in your case, why do you need to use featured articles? The same can be achieved by using categories or even tags (more work in the template overrides)

Comment: I don't want to pass in index.php, it is just an artifact that someone can type that in and get to a page I don't want them to see. I don't need to use feature articles I guess, I'd like to know more how I can make this work with categories?